# Simply make a label say Hello World in Cocoa (Mac programming)

Tags: macos, cocoa, label

I'm a total newbie to programming in cocoa for the mac so this question is probably easy.  I have a window, and on that window I have a Label.

I want to be able to update this label from my program with the current status or what's going on (eg. reading in file, parsing, etc.).  My problem is that I don't know how to access the label and change it's text property.  I tried "MyWindowName." hoping I would be able to reference the label from the Window.  I don't even know what the labels name is, or even if it has a name.

How do I reference this label in my program to change it?

Comment: I think an example may be the best way to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to go here and walk through some tutorials: http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/

A quick summary is that unlike other technologies, you don't access the controls directly (or shouldn't access them). Instead, you create outlets in a controller, which you then graphically connect to the controls and they update automagically. These tutorials will show you the way.

Comment: "...which you then graphically connect to the controls and they update automagically" You seem to be mixing connecting outlets in Interface Builder with Cocoa Bindings. The two are separate.

Comment: Quite possibly... I almost always use a mixture of both. So, it may not be "automagically", but it will be just a single line of code to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A label is just an `NSTextField` with different settings about editing/fonts, etc.  Just make an outlet in your controller that connects to the view in Interface Builder, and you can change it like you would any other `NSTextField`.

Comment: I really wish I understood more of what that meant.  I assume that my "controller" is the window, and an "outlet" is sort of like a handle that I can reference in my code, is this right?  
Would you happen to know of an example?

Comment: Your controller is whatever object you made to be the controller.  Have you done any of the Cocoa tutorials?  Most cover this sort of stuff in the first 5 pages or so...

Comment: Daisetsu: No, a window (instance of NSWindow or of any subclass thereof) is not a controller. As for your definition of outlet, I suspect you're using the term with a specific meaning from a frame of reference that I don't have, so I can't fairly evaluate your guess's accuracy. To clear up both matters, you should read through the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/